# Finding shallowest path through matrix

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, path-finding

I was hoping I could get some advice as to an appropriate algorithm to find the shallowest (least-steep) path between two point in my matrix/graph.

I've attached a plot of the matrix below.  I would like an algorithm that goes from 'B'eginning to 'E'nd.  By eye, it's pretty obvious what the path is (South-East from B then North-East to E) always staying on the reddish colour.

The length of the path is irrelevant.

The colours represents the z-axis and is from 0->1.  Yellow (brightest) is 1 and blue (darkest) is 0.  I wish to go from B->E with the z value changing least as possible along the way; thus, I want to essentially stay on the same colour (or rather, I don't want the colour to change much) as I go from B->E.

[image: matrix]

Comment: Can  you edit to add a note about how the colors of the pixels constrain what's considered a valid path?

Comment: Hmm this looks like the problem of finding a geodesic on a surface z=f(x,y) between two points. Looks like a nontrivial computational geometry problem. I'd need to look through some references...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an heuristic pathfinding algorithm like [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) and using the difference between cells as weight. Think of it as a weighted graph, where the weight of the edges is given by the difference of the cell values (so the less steep, the cheaper it is).

Of course this optimizes for local steep-ness, though I'm not sure how close to the global optimum it would be.